# LWJGL 3, VAO and Shader not rendering

Tags: java, opengl, shader, lwjgl, vao

I am using LWJGL 3 and Shaders with VAO's. My current implementation does not draw the VAO when using the shaders. However the VAO will draw when not using shaders but the VAO will be white. My question is what am I missing in my shader setup that is preventing me from seeing the VAO when using shaders?

Main Class.
Shader and VAO setup is in the gameStart() method.

```
public class Test {

/** Window Properties **/
private int 
    HEIGHT = 800,
    WIDTH = 1200,
    RESIZABLE = GL11.GL_FALSE,
    REFRESH_RATE = 60;

private String TITLE = "test";

// The window handler
private long window;

// callback reference instances
private GLFWErrorCallback errorCallback;
private GLFWKeyCallback   keyCallback;

private void preWindowSetup() {
    // Setup an error callback
    GLFW.glfwSetErrorCallback(errorCallback = errorCallbackPrint(System.err));

    // Initialize GLFW
    if (GLFW.glfwInit() != GL11.GL_TRUE)
        exit();
}

private void windowSetup() {
    // Configure Window Properties
    glfwDefaultWindowHints();
    GLFW.glfwWindowHint(GLFW_VISIBLE, GL_FALSE); // Keep the window hidden
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, RESIZABLE); // Do not allow resizing
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_REFRESH_RATE, REFRESH_RATE); // Refresh rate

    // Create the window
    window = glfwCreateWindow(WIDTH, HEIGHT, TITLE, NULL, NULL);
    if ( window == NULL )
        exit();

    // Get the resolution of the primary monitor
    ByteBuffer vidmode = glfwGetVideoMode(glfwGetPrimaryMonitor());
    // Center our window
    glfwSetWindowPos(
        window,
        (GLFWvidmode.width(vidmode) - WIDTH) / 2,
        (GLFWvidmode.height(vidmode) - HEIGHT) / 2
    );
}

private void callbackSetup() {
    // Setup a key callback. It will be called every time a key is pressed, repeated or released.
    glfwSetKeyCallback(window, keyCallback = new GLFWKeyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void invoke(long window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods) {//TODO Dispatch key events
            if (key == GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE && action == GLFW_RELEASE)
                Tasker.executeASyncTask("GLFW_MAIN_THREAD");
        }
    });
}

public void initGL() {
    preWindowSetup();
    windowSetup();
    callbackSetup();

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);     // Make the OpenGL context current
    glfwShowWindow(window);             // Make the window visible
    GLContext.createFromCurrent();      // Bind lwjgl with GLFW

    // Initialize openGl
    GL11.glViewport(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    GL11.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION);
    GL11.glLoadIdentity();
    GL11.glOrtho(0, WIDTH, 0, HEIGHT, 1, -1);
    GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);

    // Enable alpha transparency (for overlay image)
    GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_BLEND);
    GL11.glBlendFunc(GL11.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL11.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    GL11.glDepthFunc(GL11.GL_LEQUAL);
    GL11.glShadeModel(GL11.GL_SMOOTH);
}

public void gameStart() {

    System.out.println("LWJGL Version: ["+Sys.getVersion()+"]");
    System.out.println("OpenGL Version: ["+GL11.glGetString(GL11.GL_VERSION)+"]");

    // ===============================================================================================

    // =================== Shader Setup =====================
    String vertPath = "src/test/java/org/ajgl/test/graphics/shaders/VertexShaderTest.glsl";
    String fragPath = "src/test/java/org/ajgl/test/graphics/shaders/FragmentShaderTest.glsl";

    int sahderVert = GL20.glCreateShader(GL20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    GL20.glShaderSource(sahderVert, Shader.loadShader(vertPath));
    GL20.glCompileShader(sahderVert);

    int sahderFrag = GL20.glCreateShader(GL20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    GL20.glShaderSource(sahderFrag, Shader.loadShader(fragPath));
    GL20.glCompileShader(sahderFrag);
    // =================== Shader Setup =====================

    // =================== Shader Check =====================
    int status = GL20.glGetShaderi(sahderVert, GL20.GL_COMPILE_STATUS);
    if (status != GL11.GL_TRUE) {
        throw new RuntimeException(GL20.glGetShaderInfoLog(sahderVert));
    }

    int statusN = GL20.glGetShaderi(sahderFrag, GL20.GL_COMPILE_STATUS);
    if (statusN != GL11.GL_TRUE) {
        throw new RuntimeException(GL20.glGetShaderInfoLog(sahderFrag));
    }
    // =================== Shader Check =====================

    // =================== Shader Program ===================
    int programID = GL20.glCreateProgram();

    GL20.glAttachShader(programID, sahderVert);
    GL20.glAttachShader(programID, sahderFrag);

    GL20.glBindAttribLocation(programID, 0, "position");
    GL20.glBindAttribLocation(programID, 1, "color");

    GL20.glLinkProgram(programID);
    // =================== Shader Program ===================

    // =============== Shader Program Check =================
    int statusP = GL20.glGetProgrami(programID, GL20.GL_LINK_STATUS);
    if (statusP != GL11.GL_TRUE) {
        throw new RuntimeException(GL20.glGetProgramInfoLog(programID));
    }
    // =============== Shader Program Check =================

    // =================== VAO Setup ========================
    FloatBuffer vertexBufferVAO = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(9);
    vertexBufferVAO.put(new float[]{600,10,0, 550,50,0, 500,10,0});
    vertexBufferVAO.flip();

    FloatBuffer colorBufferVAO = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(9);
    colorBufferVAO.put(new float[]{1,0,0, 0,1,0, 0,0,1});
    colorBufferVAO.flip();

    int vaoID = GL30.glGenVertexArrays();
    GL30.glBindVertexArray(vaoID);
    {
        int vertHandle = GL15.glGenBuffers();
        GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertHandle);
        GL15.glBufferData(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBufferVAO, GL15.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        GL20.glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL11.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

        int colorHandle = GL15.glGenBuffers();
        GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorHandle);
        GL15.glBufferData(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorBufferVAO, GL15.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        GL20.glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL11.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
        GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    }
    GL30.glBindVertexArray(0);

    // =================== VAO Setup ========================

    // ===============================================================================================

    while ( glfwWindowShouldClose(window) == GL_FALSE ) {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        // Run Cycles
        input();

        GL20.glUseProgram(programID);

        GL30.glBindVertexArray(vaoID);
        {
            GL20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
            GL20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

            GL11.glDrawArrays(GL11.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

            GL20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
            GL20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
        }
        GL30.glBindVertexArray(0);

        GL20.glUseProgram(0);

        // Display Buffer swap
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    }

    // Release window and window call backs
    glfwDestroyWindow(window);
    keyCallback.release();
    exit();
}

private void input() {
    glfwPollEvents();
    Tasker.executeASyncTask("GLFW_MAIN_THREAD");
}

public void exit() {
    // Terminate GLFW and release the GLFWerrorfun
    glfwTerminate();
    errorCallback.release();
    System.exit(1);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Test test = new Test();
    test.initGL();
    test.gameStart();
}

}
```

Shader class.

```
public class Shader {

    public static CharSequence loadShader(String path) {
        StringBuilder shaderSource = new StringBuilder();
        int shaderID = 0;

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                shaderSource.append(line).append("\n");
            }
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Could not read file.");
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        return shaderSource;
    }
}
```

Vertex and fragment shaders.

```
// Vertex Shader
#version 400

in vec3 position;
in vec3 color;

out vec3 Color;

void main()
{
    Color = color;
    gl_Position = vec4(position, 1.0);
}

// Fragment shader
#version 400

in vec3 Color;

out vec4 fragColor;

void main()
{
    fragColor = vec4(Color, 1.0);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to the problem using this site [here](https://open.gl/drawing). The issue is that I was not using device coordinates as said in the link. Instead I was Using the cartesian coordinate system.

The fix.

```
FloatBuffer vertexBufferVAO = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(9);
**vertexBufferVAO.put(new float[]{{-0.95f,-0.95f,0, -0.5f,-0.95f,0, -0.95f,-0.5f,0});
vertexBufferVAO.flip();
```